# SharePoint Designer workflow question

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have created a new workflow in SharePoint designer 2013 in which when a date has been reached then the users needs to be informed that one section if missing needs to be completed. But I want to know that how can I do it automated because there are 3 options with the checkbox which says in short:

- When an item is created
- Changed
- Manual start

How can I do this is SharePoint Designer 2013 so that it knows when a date has been approached and will inform the user about it. Without any change in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger your workflow on **When an item is created** trigger.

Then you need to use **Pause Until Date** action in SharePoint designer 2013 workflow which:

> Causes a workflow to pause executing until a specified date and time.

After this workflow action, you can send an email to your targeted users to inform to fill necessary information.

**Reference**: [Workflow actions in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform#workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2013).

Comment: That's right and it worked. Thank you!!!!!!